# The word "class" in questions about grades/years

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does the word "class" sound idiomatic in questions about grades/years at school, e.g.: What class are you in?

Is it acceptable to say: "I'm in (the) fourth class" (see [here](http://www.ballyfinns.ie/fourth-class.html))? (I've added this question after placing my post here.)

Comment: In BrE, *what year are you in?* will lead to a response such as *year 7* whereas *what class are you in?* will lead to a response such as *class 7B* (since most schools have more than one class in each year). (*What grade are you in?* won't necessarily be understood by British children.)  Could be different in American English, though.

Comment: In the US, **class** in an academic context refers to a course on a subject in a school where the students move from room to room for their different subjects (*She's in our geometry class*) or to one's graduating year in high school or college/university (*She is in the class of 2018*) or to the students, en masse, in one of the years in high school or college (*We have a very talented freshman class this year*)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the region, as rjpond said. In InE, we are *now* shifting to 'grade.' *Which grade you are in?* ~ Grade 7. As a kid, I had always answered 'Which class you are in?' ~ 7th Class!

Interestingly, ***in InE***, 'years' are generally for the 'colleges' and not 'schools.' Say if you are in *year 3,* it would mean that you are in a college and in third year of some professional course.

In practice are all three: years, grades, and classes.

[Here](http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/british-american-english.html) and [here](http://www.studyenglishtoday.net/british-american-english.html) are the comparisons.